# CDHtmlDialog not loading latest version of IE?

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++, mfc

I need to embed a browser control into an MFC window or a dialog and have it display an HTML page. 
So I create a CDHtmlDialog - derived class, and use the CDHtmlDialog::Navigate() method to display the page. I am using visual Studio 2013.

Everything works fine, except 2D transforms don't work, and I need those to rotate some images. When I check for the IE version online (from inside the embedded control, using http://www.thismachine.info/, for example) - I get:

*Internet Explorer 7.0 on Windows 8 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.3)*

Whereas if I go the the same address from the default browser installed on my Windows 8 machine, I get:

*Internet Explorer 10.0 on Windows 8, Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)*

I don't even have the IE 7 installed. What am I missing? Can I make the CDHtmlDialog use a later version of the browser? If not, what is the preferred way of rendering HTML 5 content in a C++ (Windows) window?

Thanks!

Comment: The embedded web browser stays in that old mode unless an obscure registry setting is used. Refer to the answers for these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874565/how-to-set-ie9-by-default-for-web-browser  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456490/how-to-set-feature-browser-emulation-to-ie8-mode

Comment: Awesome, that was it, thanks! Why don't you copy paste your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as a solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded web browser stays in that old mode unless an obscure registry setting is used.

Rather than me reproducing what has already been written, you can refer to the answers for these questions:

[How to set IE9 by default for web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874565/how-to-set-ie9-by-default-for-web-browser)

[How to set FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION to IE8 mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456490/how-to-set-feature-browser-emulation-to-ie8-mode)