# When navigating to a web site using webbrowser control the web site look mess how can i fix it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If i navigate to google.com it will look fine like in chrome.
But if i navigate to a site maybe the problem it's in hebrew not sure for example to http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/addmsg/393/
An hebrew site. Then everything is mess i mean textboxes and images in the site not in places. But browsing to this site from chrome is looking fine.

I just navigate to the site regular:
In form1 constructor:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser4_DocumentCompleted;
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/addmsg/393");
```

And in documentcompleted just checking until the page loaded:

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri != webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

The result i get using the webBrowser is this screenshot:

[Mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpgDk.jpg)

Comment: Lookup FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION and learn how to set it in the registry. There's a thread on it here if I can find it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set IE9 by default for web browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874565/how-to-set-ie9-by-default-for-web-browser)